# GoogleApiClient.isConnected() Error in BaseGameUtilities

Tags: java, android, google-play-games, google-api-client, leaderboard

I am Trying to build a app that will use leaderboard feature of Google Play Game Service. I am taking help from the tutorial [Google Play Game Services: Leaderboards](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-leaderboards--cms-20700)

I am using exactly the same source code used in this tutorial and following all the instruction given. When I run the code, it crashes by showing the following logcat output

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.isConnected()' was expected to be of type interface but instead was found to be of type virtual (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.onStart(GameHelper.java:393)
```

Here is the link of the [Game.java](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java) class

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: It seems the reflection implementation is different for [art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime) than for [dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)), and it seems this inconsistency has caused the method to fail.  Are you using the most up to date libraries offered by Google? Read more about your specific problem [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3mehbb/breaking_changes_in_google_play_services_81/).

Comment: Thanks MeetTitan. Y our comment helped me to solve the problem.